# find conditional probability of the new variable

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

I am actually trying to understand the problem that how we convert our given variables into new variable and proceed them for solution in conditional probabilities, let i have two variables 
suppose $X_1$ and $X_2$ are iid normal $(\mu , \sigma_2^2)$ find distribution of $Y=\frac{X_1}{X_2}$

Answer (score 1):

### Ratio case

The ratio of two standard normal distribution is the [Cauchy distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_distribution). You can follow similar steps in the proof provided in [this document](http://www.math.wm.edu/%7Eleemis/chart/UDR/PDFs/StandardnormalStandardcauchy.pdf) for the non standard case.

---

### Log case

If $X \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu,\sigma^2)$ then $Y = \ln X$ will behave as
\begin{align}
f_Y(y) & = \frac {\rm d}{{\rm d}y} \Pr(Y \le y) = 
\frac {\rm d}{{\rm d}y} \Pr(\ln X \le y) \\[6pt]
& = \frac {\rm d}{{\rm d}y} \Phi\left( \frac{e^y -\mu} \sigma \right) \\[6pt]
& = \varphi\left( \frac{e^y - \mu} \sigma \right) \frac {\rm d}{{\rm d}y} \left( \frac{e^y - \mu} \sigma \right) \\[6pt]
& = \varphi\left( \frac{e^y - \mu} \sigma \right) \frac {e^y} {\sigma} \\[6pt]
& = \frac {e^y} {\sigma}  \frac 1 {\sqrt{2\pi\,}} \exp\left( -\frac{(e^y-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2} \right).
\end{align}
where $\Phi,\varphi$ are the CDF and PDF of the standard normal distribution, respectively.

Comment: i m more interested in first one sir , Y=x1\x2 plz ans for that as well

Comment: i have edited, please check

Comment: that is very helpful document , thank so much sir

Comment: plz answer this question sir
if (x,y) b a random variable continuous with pdf f what will b pdf's of U= x+y , V= x-y